# how to set fix width in to table td field?

Tags: html, css

Hy I"m setting up a table data using datatable but the problem is that table  td filed not set to fixed width in to the table can anyone help me?

```
<style>

    #mytable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1), #mytable > thead > tr > th:nth-child(1) {width:5%; text-align: center;}
    #mytable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2), #mytable > thead > tr > th:nth-child(2) {width:10%;text-align: right;}
    #mytable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(3), #mytable > thead > tr > th:nth-child(3) {width:20%;text-align: right;}
    #mytable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(4), #mytable > thead > tr > th :nth-child(4) {width:10%;text-align: right;}
    #mytable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(5), #mytable > thead > tr > th:nth-child(5) {width:5%;text-align: right;}
    #mytable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(6), #mytable > thead > tr > th:nth-child(6) {width:5%;text-align: right;}
    #mytable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(7), #mytable > thead > tr > th:nth-child(7) {width:10%;text-align: right; border-left: 1px solid #dee2e6;}
    #mytable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(8), #mytable > thead > tr > th:nth-child(8) {width:35%;text-align: right;}
    #mytable > thead > tr > th { text-align: center !important; };
</style>

<table id="mytable" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width: 100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>name </th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone</th>
            <th>add</th>
            <th>city</th>
            <th>contry</th>
            <th>zip code</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>test table</td>
            <td>test table</td>
            <td>test table test table test table agin</td>
            <td>test table</td>
            <td>test table</td>
            <td>test table</td>
            <td>test table</td>
            <td>test table test  test demo</td>

        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

overflow email column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one. Hope it works. Please leave a response in comment.

```
 table {
     table-layout: fixed;
}
 td{
     white-space: nowrap;
     overflow: hidden;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add DIV in TD and add width to that DIV

Comment: thanks a lot for your help  and i will up yr answer when my reputation will > 15

Comment: If the answer works for you you can make the answer accepted by the green tik !

Comment: @NileshPandit: you can mark it as correct answer for now. it will help others. Mark it up later.

Answer (score 0):

`.table { table-layout: fixed }`

Comment: I have try this one but problem are same because layout are automatic set in the table

Comment: id `mytable` is not found in html.

Comment: <table id="patient" change to <table id="mytable"

Answer (score 0):

you can set the width of  by using CSS like 
 if you put specific percentage of width for  it was make fixed for   as

```
<th width="10%">
```

it restrict td value also

Comment: i was again answer with some example

Answer (score 0):

you can fix the total width within `100%` as per your table data

```
<th width="3%">S.no</th>
<th width="10%"> Date</th>
<th width="10%">branch</th>
<th width="10%">Employee</th>
<th width="10%"> Name</th>
<th width="10%">Contact</th>
<th width="17%">Questions</th>
<th width="5%">Question Type</th>
<th width="10%">Answer</th>
<th width="5%">Order ID</th>
<th width="5%">Order Value</th>
```